# Primary Category '$' bug?

Tags: add-on, channel-entries, categories, solspace

I've just updated my version of [Primary Category](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/primary_category/) from Solspace from version 2.0.2 to 2.2.1 in my EE 2.5.2 install and run into what I think is a bug. A BIG change in the update is that you now need to wrap your primary category variables inside a `{primary_categories}` tag pair inside the channel entries tag (in the past you could just use the primary category variables inside channel entries without the wrapper). So I updated my templates, but when I put in the wrapper tags I had some channel entries that suddenly were displaying duplicate and broken content. After investigating I found the common thread for the broken entries was that they had channel field content that contained the '$' symbol. So for example a reference to a price, like $1,099.00, in the title or body. This appears to be a bug in Primary Category.

Has anyone run across this same issue and if so do you have a fix or work around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This obviously needs to be tested, but I was able to find this article and employing the solution it offered seems to work:

http://www.procata.com/blog/archives/2005/11/13/two-preg_replace-escaping-gotchas/

The issue is that the '$' has significance in the preg_replace replacement pattern so the $1 in the $1,099 becomes a back reference.

Just before line 1198 in the `ext.primary_category.php` file I added this line:

`$tag_pair_data = preg_replace('/(\$|\\\\)(?=\d)/', '\\\\\1', $tag_pair_data);`

This seems to have resolved the bug for me. I've forwarded my findings to Solspace and I am posting this here just for completeness. Personally I would wait for an official fix from Solspace, but if you're brave (or desperate) you might try this.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed appears to be an (odd) bug in Primary Category, which is reported. This seems to affect only dollar signs followed by numbers only (i.e. `$hello` gets parsed correctly, but not `$123`, which outputs `3`).

One workaround I found was to avoid having the dollar sign followed immediately by a number. Adding a space between the $ and number seems to prevent the odd parsing.

Eg. Change `$1,009.00` to `$ 1,009.00` (please note the space).

Comment: Hey I just upgraded to version 2.2.2 and looks like this issue still isn't fixed. A possible fix is in my post below if you want to take a look and see if that is worth rolling into the next update?

Comment: Just a note, that I changed my upvote and acceptance of this answer because in hindsight this is more of a workaround than a real fix. It's not really correct to have a space between the dollar sign and amount in your entry. The fix I mention below seems to work. We've had it deployed on our production site for over nine months without any noticeable issues.