# Solspace Primary Category returning the primary category id twice

Tags: solspace, primary-category

I recently upgraded to Primary Category 2.2.1
The following code is returning the primary category id twice

Has anyone had a similar problem with duplication?

```
{exp:primary_category category_group="2"}
    {primary_category_id}
{/exp:primary_category}
```

regards,
Ciaran

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `entry_id=""` parameter to `{exp:primary_category}`. By providing an entry_id, you let Primary Category know which primary categories to display for that entry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this has not solved the problem. I have found an article that references a possible bug relating to the $ character: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12740/primary-category-bug

This could be relevant as the only entries I have that do not experience this duplication problem are included in a Primary Category with a $ character in the Category Name field

Comment: Do you have more context for the {exp:primary_category} tag code you have above? Is it inside another tag, using other variables, 3rd-party tags, etc? If so, please provide this code context in your OP :) Also, if $ is relevant, please give an example of where $ is used.

Comment: Hi,
I've stripped it down to this:

Comment: <html>
<body>
{exp:channel:entries channel="products"}
<!-- BREADCRUMBS -->
{exp:primary_category category_group="2" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{primary_category_id}
{/exp:primary_category} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
</body>
</html>

Comment: I've stripped the template down to the code above. Still returning primary_category_id twice

Comment: I'm unsure if $ is relevant. When I first upgraded the problem did not exist for entries that had been assigned a Primary Category with $ in the title. However, I have tried adding the $ sign to other categories and this has not removed the duplication issue

Comment: Having trouble reproducing this on my side. Is your `{exp:channel:entries}` tag outputting more than one entry? Do you have more than one primary category assigned to any of your entries? Also, if possible please add your additional code context to the OP so other users can see it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a database issue. I had duplicate entries in my exp_primary_category table. I think this may have been due to problems I had while upgrading Primary Category.

Solution:
Using 'Sequel Pro' I connected to DB, and ran the following query to create a new database table containing only unique rows from exp_primary_category:
"create table exp_primary_category2 as select distinct * from exp_primary_category;"

I then renamed 'exp_primary_category' to 'exp_primary_category-old' (just in case anything went wrong with new table) and named my new table 'exp_primary_category'.

Everything back to normal now!
Thanks for the help